# How to convert HTTP Web Response to IFormFile in C#

Tags: c#, file, httpresponse, file-conversion, iformfile

I am recieving a url from frontend.
I need to hit this url (a http request) and then validate the content of the file. I need to check whether this url is a image file or not.

Upon making the HTTP request, I got the HTTP Web Response. And I am stuck here. I tried converting this web response to byte array and then byte array to stream. So that I can pass this stream to FormFile class constructor to create file object and then validate the file content.

But upon converting to stream, the stream object is created with some exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlnCQ.jpg)
So passing this stream object to FileForm constructor is giving me a file. But even that file got created with few exceptions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZnxc.jpg)
I don't know how to proceed further.

This is how I decided to validate file.
const int imageMinimumBytes = 512;

```
if (file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpg" &&
                    file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/jpeg" &&
                    file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/pjpeg" &&
                    file.ContentType.ToLower() != "image/png")
            {
                throw new IamException("Invalid image. Supported image types are JPG/JPEG/PNG");
            }
            
            
            if (Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg"
                && Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() != ".png"
                && Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpeg")
            {
                throw new IamException("Invalid image. Supported image types are JPG/JPEG/PNG");
            }
            
            if (!file.OpenReadStream().CanRead)
            {
                throw new IamException("Invalid image. Supported image types are JPG/JPEG/PNG");
            }
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[imageMinimumBytes];
            file.OpenReadStream().Read(buffer, 0, imageMinimumBytes);
            string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            
            if (Regex.IsMatch(content,
                    @"<script|<html|<head|<title|<body|<pre|<table|<a\s+href|<img|<plaintext|<cross\-domain\-policy",
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Multiline))
            {
                throw new IamException("Invalid image. Supported image types are JPG/JPEG/PNG");
            }type here
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get/load the whole file to your memory if you only need to validate the file, you can get content type directly from the response headers(using the HEAD request method)

```
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD"; // use HEAD method to retrieve only headers
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{
    string contentType = response.ContentType;
}
```